# Wordpress spl_autoload_register not working with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, spl-autoload-register

So i'm making a wordpress website where I want to migrate my wordpress website to an online hosting platform. I did that with the all-in-one Wp Migration plugin, but i got a critical error message.

I fixed it and looked in the directadmin panel for apache errors. The problem is the custom theme I am making. I'm using an spl_autoload_register function from php and it gives the following error in directadmin:

> Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Website\Backend' not found in

The code i'm using for my autoload function is this:
File: **functions.php**

```php
include __DIR__ . '/autoloader.php' ;
$backend = new Website\Backend();
```

File: **autoloader.php**

```php
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $className = str_replace(__NAMESPACE__, '', $className);

    $path = __DIR__ . '/classes/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . ".class.php";
    if(file_exists($path)) {
        include $path;
    }
    return;
});
```

file: **backend.php**

```php
    namespace Website;
    class Backend 
    {    

    }
```

folderstructure:

- classes/

  - website/

    - backend.class.php
- functions.php
- index.php

**Works on local server but not on hosting**
**Anything doing wrong here?**

Comment: Hi Eric, you are using Composer to import your dependencies I guess?

Comment: I am not using composer. Just plain php and the wordpress class

Comment: try to display `$path` and see what the value of `$path` is, be sure that `spl_autoload_register` is executed, check if the files exist in `website`, try with a different namespace, instead `namespace Website` try `namespace Classes\Website` but the logic of your code seems OK to me

Comment: yeah it just was the path that was wrong, especially the capital letters in the path that were giving the error.